# Validate values with types in runtime

Tags: typescript

We need to validate types and values during runtime when we call our apis.

There are several different types, so we need to have a generic solution. I have in mind this:

```
function isThing(value: unknown) => value is Thing
```

Where *is* is the time travel from runtime to compile time, and returns a boolean where true tells TypeScript that value is thing and false that value is not thing. Pseudo-code:

```
 const v: (unknown | undefined) = getSomething();
    // code executed at runtime
    if (isThing(v)) {
      // the isThing() test returned true, so in this scope
      // v: Thing
      // which in turn informs which operations are available
      // and possible at compile time
      v.doThingThing(v.thingProperty);
    } else {
      // since isThing() returned false, we know it's not a
      // Thing, so we haven't learned anything, we still have
      // v: unknown | undefined
      if(v != null) {
        // null checks and some functions also inform the compiler
        // v is unknown but no undefined
      } else {
        // v must be undefined
      }
    }
```

Have anyone clue about how to implement something like this?

Comment: `if (v instanceof Thing) { ... }` maybe? Or do you specifically need to use an extra function `isThing( value: unknown )`?

Comment: Are you just looking to implement a User-defined Type-guard? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards I recall that these needed to be implemented as true `function` and not as `fat arrow functions`

Comment: @Todd Arrow functions can have a type predicate, i.e. (`(v: any): v is string => typeof v === "string"`)